# What is the reason for this erratic behavior in `time-subtract`?

Tags: org-mode, time-date

I am attempting to calculate some time differences in org time strings using `time-subtract`.

```
(time-subtract (org-parse-time-string "2018-04-16 Mon 14:00") 
               (org-parse-time-string "2018-04-14 Sat 13:00"))

=> (0 0 1 2)
```

This seems to make sense. The two times are different by two days and one hour.

```
(time-subtract (org-parse-time-string "2018-04-16 Mon 14:00") 
               (org-parse-time-string "2018-04-11 Wed 18:00"))

=> (-1 65535 999996 5)
```

This one doesn't come out as neatly. I would expect `(0 0 1 5)`.

Here is the documentation for `time-subtract`.

```
time-subtract is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.

(time-subtract A B)

Return the difference between two time values A and B, as a time value.
Use ‘float-time’ to convert the difference into elapsed seconds.
A nil value for either argument stands for the current time.
See ‘current-time-string’ for the various forms of a time value.
```

If I try `float-time` on the two examples above, I get `1.000002e-06` and `-3.999994078185409e-06`, which implies to me that I'm doing something wrong.

The documentation on `current-time-string` does not appear to be helpful. In particular it does not define the four fields producted by `time-subtract`.

What is going on here? How can I get a consistent time difference between two `org-mode` timestamps?

Comment: This doesn't explain the erratic behavior, but I did end up getting a consistent time difference by using `(time-to-seconds (apply 'encode-time (org-parse-time-string …)))` instead of `time-subtract`.

Comment: `org-parse-time-string`, like `parse-time-string` and `decode-time`, returns a list `(SEC MIN HOUR DAY MON YEAR DOW DST TZ)`. This is not a valid argument to `time-subtract`, which expects what Emacs calls a "time value", namely a list `(HIGH LOW USEC PICO)`. See [`(elisp) Time of Day`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-of-Day.html), [`(elisp) Time Conversion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Conversion.html), and [`(elisp) Time Parsing`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Parsing.html).

Answer (score 1):

```el
(time-subtract
 (apply #'encode-time (org-parse-time-string "2018-04-16 Mon 14:00")) 
 (apply #'encode-time (org-parse-time-string "2018-04-11 Wed 18:00")))
;; => (6 24384)

(time-to-seconds '(6 24384))
;; => 417600.0

(format-seconds "%Y, %D, %H, %M, %z%S" 417600.0)
;; => "4 days, 20 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds"
```

Emacs can represent a timestamp in different forms, for example, 12
hours after Unix epoch, or `1970-01-01T12:00:00Z`

```
;; 1. Seconds as a float number
(* 12.0 3600)
;; => 43200.0

;; 2. Seconds as a list
;; (SEC-HIGH SEC-LOW MICROSEC PICOSEC)
;; HIGH * 2**16 + LOW + MICRO * 10**-6 + PICO * 10**-12
(0 43200 0 0)

;; 3. Calendar
(SEC MINUTE HOUR DAY MONTH YEAR DOW DST UTCOFF)
(0   0      12   1   1     1970 4   nil 0)
```